# Newly upvoted cool comments get an uncolored score

Tags: bug, comments, design

I brought this up about 4 months ago on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284223/2767207), but because this problem is not only on Stack Overflow, but all other Stack Exchange sites, I'll post it again here.

Thanks to [tbodt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1455016), the [correct fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284394/2767207) was found, but it still hasn't taken effect. *Obviously* this isn't a high priority, but seeing as it's fairly easy to fix (and the code was fixed by tbodt), why not fix it now?

Here's the post

---

I just noticed while upvoting a comment today, that right after it is upvoted, the color of the `cool` comment score became black:

[image: Black vote count on comment]

but, once I refreshed the page, and from then on, it became grey:

[image: Grey vote count on comment]

I also noticed that the HTML for the comment score that was initially upvoted (the non-colored one) was:

```html
<td class=" comment-score">
    <span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class>1</span>
</td>
```

Whereas the HTML for the comment score after the page was refreshed is:

```html
<td class=" comment-score">
    <span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span>
</td>
```

This only happens on `cool` comments (ones with score < 5), and on all Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: There were [3446](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them#comment651_250156) open bugs last year, with  let's say half of them easy fixable within one hour. That is still a lot of work... just wait for another 6-8 months....

Comment: What is a "cool" comment?

Comment: @Wildcard It's the internal name for comments with a score < 5